# Is this undefined behaviour? (std::set::erase(it++);)

Tags: c++

Found this (simplified version below) in some old code and the Debugger (VC++ 2015) did not complain about an invalid iterator while executing it.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
int main() {
    std::set<int> s = {0,1,2,3,4};
    auto it = std::begin(s);
    while (it != std::end(s))
    {
        if (*it % 2 == 0)
            s.erase(it++); // UB?
        else
            ++it;
    }
}
```

I know it should be `it = s.erase(it);` instead, but I was wondering if this actually is undefined behaviour. Is it, or is there something going on that renders the code OK?

[The documentation says "References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.""](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase)

The following would of course be undefined:

```
s.erase(it);
++it
```

And the now following would be OK:

```
auto temp = it;
++temp;
s.erase(it);
it = temp;
```

But what about my code above?

```
s.erase(it++);
```

Comment: Its fine.  Unlike a vector only the current iterator is invalidated.

Comment: According to [the doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase) only iterators to the element being erased are invalidated, any other is fine. (and since post-incr returns the non-incremented value...)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. Sill I have a question left. Just edited my post accordingly.

Comment: `it++` gives you two different iterators.  The function gets what the iterator was before incrementing and the loop has the next iterator.  It basically does what your OK example does.

Comment: Great. Thank you Nathan.

Comment: OK, and by implementing a dummy-version of operator++ I also understand why the code is equivalent to the OK version: http://ideone.com/UWOsFq